# Correct way of commenting on commands in python

Tags: python, comments

I know two ways of leaving comments in python. One is using `"""` and the other is using `#`. I know that the first can be used to return a functions help as a benefit. But when should I use one and when the other? And also how do I have to leave comments? Do I have to press tab and arrange the first line of comment with the the command beneath it? Or do I have to start from the beginning of the line?

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is only [**one** way of commenting, using `#`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#comments):

> A comment starts with a hash character (#) that is not part of a string literal, and ends at the end of the physical line.

Triple quoting, `"""`, creates a string object, which happens to be used as the docstring when it is the first line of a function, module or a a class. Triple quoting is useful in many other places too, but should not be confused with commenting. You can use a triple quoted string like any other string literal, with the specific benefit that you can use actual newlines in your source code instead of having to use `\n` escape characters.

Although it *can* be used to disable a block of code by turning it into a multi-line string instead, you really should *not* do this. Use proper source code control and simply delete the block, or use an editor that lets you comment out whole blocks by inserting `#` for you instead.

For actual comments, use `#`. The [Python style guide (PEP 8)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments) has some things to say about when and how to use commenting; it has this to say about indentation:

> Block comments generally apply to some (or all) code that follows them, and are indented to the same level as that code. Each line of a block comment starts with a # and a single space (unless it is indented text inside the comment).